# Delete undeleteable folder

Tags: windows, cygwin, windows-vista

I was installing Cygwin and something went wrong.  Now, I have a folder named `#endif` and no matter what I do, I can't seem to delete it.  I've tried deleting and renaming the folder in Windows Explorer and through the command prompt.  The command prompt tells me "This system cannot find the file specified."

Any ideas on how to delete it.  The folder is located in `C:/cygwin`.

Comment: Try deleting it with administrative rights. Try the below link. http://www.it-support.com.au/how-to-delete-system-files-or-a-system-folder-in-windows-7-using-the-windows-interface/2013/01/

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either.  The Security tab states, "The requested security information is either unavailable or can't be displayed."  My account is an Admin so I shouldn't have a rights issue.

Comment: You must have the administrative rights to do that. User with limited rights cannot do it.

Comment: My account is an administrator.  I have the rights to do it, it just doesn't seem to be working for this folder.

Answer (score 1):

Enter Command Prompt and run the following command:

chkdsk C: /f      (replace "C" with your drive letter)

If that doesn't solve the problem, your best bet would be to run Volkov Commander from a BootCD such as Hiren's BootCD (You can find it here: http://www.hirensbootcd.org/files/Hirens.BootCD.15.2.zip ) and using a command such as "deltree".
You could also try a LiveCD Linux distribution that automatically mounts the windows partitions (eg: Fedora). That could also work. Good luck!